# In the K8S environment, FluentBit outputs to Kafka, can establishes a connection and creates a topic, but generates data report error

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, fluent-bit

Ask a question.
In the K8S environment, FluentBit outputs to Kafka, can establishes a connection and creates a topic, but generates data report error.

```
[error] [output:kafka:kafka.0] fluent-bit#producer-1: [thrd:data39:9092/176]: data39:9092/176: Failed to resolve 'data39:9092': Name or service not known (after 197ms in state CONNECT)
```

I tried FluentBit1.5 and 1.6 and had the same problem.
I only changed the Kafka broker and topic in the FluentBit configuration file, everything else is the default configuration.
I checked /etc/hosts and there is no problem.

The Kafka profile is set to:
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://x.x.x.x:9092

Also, FluentBit output to ElasticSearch is normal.

Ask everyone to help, thank you very much.

Comment: it works. in fluent-bit-ds.yaml - mountPath: /etc/hosts 
          name: hosts
          readOnly: true

Comment: As you've resolved your issue,  please provide your comment as an answer with additional explanation for better visibility as the community that could stumble upon same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this answer as a community wiki as original poster of this question provided a solution to his issue in the comments.

Feel free to edit and improve this answer.

> it works. in fluent-bit-ds.yaml - mountPath: /etc/hosts name: hosts readOnly: true

The changes most probably were made to the `fluent-bit-ds.yaml` from this site:

- *[Docs.fluentbit.io: Manual: Installation: Kubernetes: Fluent-bit](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/installation/kubernetes#fluent-bit-to-elasticsearch)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kafka.apache.org](https://kafka.apache.org/)*
- *[Fluentbit.io](https://fluentbit.io/)*